# Transformation Function: Gonzalez and Woods

Tags: notation, digital-image-processing

I have been reading Image Processing from Gonzalez and Woods and in the chapter Image Transformation I have come across this equation

$$
T \left(u, v\right)
= 
\sum_{x=0}^{M-1}
{
  \sum_{y=0}^{N-1}
  {
    f \left(x, y\right)
    \,
    r \left(x, y, u, v\right)
  }
}
\,.
$$

I am unable to understand this mathematical notation. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Those ${\sum}\text{-signs}$ specify [sigma notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Capital-sigma_notation).  They're basically like `for` loops where you keep summing up the value specified in the body.

The equation,
$$
T \left(u, v\right)
= 
\sum_{x=0}^{M-1}
{
  \sum_{y=0}^{N-1}
  {
    f \left(x, y\right)
    \,
    r \left(x, y, u, v\right)
  }
}
\,,
$$

translates into:

```
public double T(double u, double v)
{
    var sum = 0.0;

    for (int x=0; x <= M-1; ++x)
    {
        for (int y=0; y <= N-1; ++y)
        {
            sum = sum + (f(x, y) * r(x, y, u, v));
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

---

In other words, it defines some function, $T \left(u, v\right) ,$ that takes two input variables: $u$ and $v .$  You also need to know two other functions: $f \left(x, y\right)$ and $r\left(x, y, u, v\right) ,$ which means you'll need at least 2 more equations.

Then:

1. Start with a starting total value of $0 .$
2. Set $x$ to $0 .$
3. Set $y$ to $0 .$
4. Calculate $f\left(x, y\right) r\left(x, y, u, v\right) ,$ then add this value to the total.

   - On the first evaluation, $x=0$ and $y=0 ,$ so that's $f\left(0, 0\right) r\left(0, 0, u, v\right) .$
5. Increment $y .$

   - If it's still less-than-or-equal-to $N - 1 ,$ then go back to Step (4).
6. Increment $x .$

   - If it's still less-than-or-equal-to $M - 1 ,$ then go back to Step (3).
7. The final total is the calculated value for $T \left(u, v\right) .$

Comment: What is r(x,y,u,v) referring to? what are those extra parameters u and v?

Comment: Are we multiplying each pixel intensity alone with that function?
any explanation showing how this works on a matrix level by taking 2 matrices will be of much help

Comment: @HIRAKMONDAL I'm not sure.  The equation is very generic, so it's hard to guess what the variables might refer to without seeing the book.  $u$ and $v$ may be coordinate positions for a pixel.  You'll probably have to read where the book declares its notation to figure out what the symbols match up to.

Answer (score 0):

With $M=3,N=2$, the expression expands to

$$\begin{align}T(u,v)=
&f(0,0)\,r(0,0,u,v)+f(0,1)\,r(0,1,u,v)+\\
&f(1,0)\,r(1,0,u,v)+f(1,1)\,r(0,1,u,v)+\\
&f(2,0)\,r(2,0,u,v)+f(2,1)\,r(0,1,u,v)\end{align}.$$

$f$ denotes an image (bidimensional array of pixel values), $T$ is the image transformed to another bidimensional array and $r$ is some function that defines the transformation.

For example, the Discrete Fourier Transform corresponds to

$$r(x,y,u,v):=e^{i(\omega_xxu+\omega_yyv)}.$$

Such transformations are obviously linear with respect to $f$.